# Jasmine jquery test event handler on

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

How to trigger event in such situation:

**Code to test:**

```
   $("body").on("touchstart", "[title]", function (event) {}
```

I'm trying to test this in this way and it doesn't work.

```
event = $.Event("touchstart", {target: "test"});
$("body, title").trigger(event);
```

Does anyone know how to test it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with   $.Event.
`$('[title]').first().trigger('touchstart', {target: "test"});` works fine